# How to add a javascript and css file in Jinja2 using Databricks Python?

Tags: python, jinja2, databricks

I am using the Databricks Python notebook, and I am trying to render the HTML file in Jinja2.  I am trying to add a Javascript and CSS file. Below is the code I have written.

I am not creating any app using flask. it's just a simple template

```
myTemplate = Template('''<html> <center><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ tpath }}" alt={{ name }} width="1200" height="90" /></center><br><h1> Hello world {{ something }}!</h1>
{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {% include "/mnt/sandbox/AWS-JDPS-MACHINE-HEALTH/Solution_PDF/myscript.js" %}
    </script>
    <!-- The contents of myscript.js will be loaded inside the script tag -->
{% endblock %}
{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mnt/sandbox/AWS-JDPS-MACHINE-HEALTH/Solution_PDF/Embed.css" />
{% endblock %}

</html>
''')
test = myTemplate.render(something="MACHINE HEALTH", tpath = file, name = 'Sample')
```

Its throwing error "No loader for this environment specified." 
As I am using Databricks environment and I am new to jinja2 and Databricks. I am not able to change the path of the environment.

Is there any other way to embed a CSS and javascript file in my template?
and when you render it - I would like an HTML file

BELOW IS THE COMPLETE ERROR -

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-11791890> in <module>()
     12 </html>
     13 ''')
---> 14 test = myTemplate.render(something="MACHINE HEALTH", tpath = file, name = 'Tarun')

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py in render(self, *args, **kwargs)
    987         except Exception:
    988             exc_info = sys.exc_info()
--> 989         return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
    990 
    991     def stream(self, *args, **kwargs):

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py in handle_exception(self, exc_info, rendered, source_hint)
    752             self.exception_handler(traceback)
    753         exc_type, exc_value, tb = traceback.standard_exc_info
--> 754         reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    755 
    756     def join_path(self, template, parent):

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
     35     def reraise(tp, value, tb=None):
     36         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
---> 37             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
     38         raise value
     39 

<template> in top-level template code()

<template> in block "javascript"()

TypeError: no loader for this environment specified
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here:

1. Ninja doesn't know anything about Databricks File System (DBFS) that is really a wrapper around specific cloud storage implementation.  That's why it's complaining about missing loader.  To access files on DBFS from software that works with local files you need to prepend the `/dbfs` prefix to the path. For example: `/dbfs/mnt/sandbox/`
2. The same with stylesheets - you can't use `href="/mnt/sandbox/...`, as the file is not accessible.  The solution here is either include stylesheet as text into HTML, so the HTML is self contained.  Or put the file into the [`/FileStore` location on DBFS](https://docs.databricks.com/data/filestore.html#save-a-file-to-filestore) (for example as `/FileStore/file_name.css`) and refer to it as `/files/file_name.css` (see documentation for more details/examples)